# Strange behavior of Docker's Image Pull Rate Limit

Tags: ubuntu, docker, containers

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server with packages `docker-ce`, `docker-ce-cli`, and `containerd.io` installed on it. When I try to pull an image from Docker Hub for the second time this day, the `toomanyrequests` error shows up but as of Docker's website, I'm allowed for about 100 pull requests per day. Is there anyone who knows what the solution to this problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a free account and login. Someone else on your network, behind the same NAT router, is pulling images on Hub without logging in. Docker only knows the public IP the requests are coming from when you don't login, and so your pulls are aggregated with others on the same network.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've actually created one before, but don't know how to use it when pulling images. Do you have any information about that?

Comment: @MBiabanpour From the CLI, run `docker login`

Comment: Thanks for your help, @BMitch !